# .htaccess URL Rewriting not working in production

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, flightphp

I am working an a small REST API with FlightPHP, and having an issue with the URL Rewriting.  It is working fine on my development machine, but when I deploy it to production I am getting 404s for all routes other than the base '/' route.  The 404 is not the typical FlightPHP 404, but the Apache/Ubuntu 404

This is what I have in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

I know .htaccess/mod_rewrite is enabled, because I also have a couple of WordPress sites hosted on this machine (a Linode VPS)

Any ideas?

Comment: There's no need for `QSA`, because you don't add a query string. Apart from that it looks fine. Maybe a `RewriteBase` issue, the error.log might tell you more.

Comment: Is this a new site? mod_rewrite is a module that's enabled server wide, however if you configure vhosts for each site you still have to enable `.htaccess` for each one. It's not automatic. `AllowOverride All`

Comment: tried adding this to apache2.conf with  an apache restart with no luck.

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>